# Join - fields in table 2 override those in table 1

Tags: mysql, join

I have a products table that stores "master" pricing:

> **products**
>   ========== .
>   id
>   partnum
>   description
>   price
>   installtime

Dealers can override the list price, setting a different price, install time, etc. My thought was to store dealer-specific differences in another table:

> **overrides**
>   ========== .
>   dealerID
>   partnum
>   price
>   installtime

When I query the db for a dealer's prices, I need to join these tables. I need the values in the overrides table to override those in the products table.

```
SELECT partnum, price, installtime FROM products  
JOIN overrides ON products.partnum = overrides.partnum  
WHERE dealerID = 123
```

As written, this would give an error of course. The point is I need the price from the overrides table if one exists instead of the price in the products table (same for instaltime). I could use different field names and move the logic to the PHP layer. But SQL should be able to handle it, right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) together with [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) to check first the overrides, and fallback if no override exists.

```
SELECT p.partnum, 
    IFNULL(d.price, p.price) AS price,
    IFNULL(d.installtime, p.installtime) AS installtime
FROM products p 
  LEFT JOIN overrides d ON d.dealerID = 123
      AND p.partnum = d.partnum
```

Note: I moved the `WHERE dealerID = 123` to the join predicate, to retrieve **all** products, and the overrides for a specific dealer.

Comment: Thanks. This works beautifully. Is there any difference between IFNULL and COALESCE? Looking at the MySQL docs, I don't see a huge distinction between them.

Comment: @skypanther No, `IFNULL` is supported by MySql, `COALESCE` is the ANSI standard and supported by all RDBMS.

Comment: well, I did tag this as a mysql question so I'll give the answer to you, though I thought long about giving it to Tyler Eaves

Answer (score 5):

Do it as a left join, and then use coalesce on each field, with the override column first. 
Coalesce returns the first non-null argument.

```
select coalesce(overrides.partnum, products.partnum) ... etc.
```

Comment: Thanks @tyler-eaves This works as well as Scrum Meister's solution. I'm not sure which to set as the answer. I'll wait to see if anyone can give me a distinction between the two functions...