# Model id is overridden by related model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an Eloquent model that has a scope method to filter some rows:

```
class TODocs extends \Eloquent {
    public function scopeUnexported($query)
    {
        $query
            ->join('to_requests', function ($join) {
                $join->on('to_requests.id', '=', 'to_docs.request_id');
                $join->whereNull('to_requests.deleted_at');
            })
            ->where('to_docs.export_allowed', true)
            ->whereNotNull('to_docs.filename')
            ->whereNull('to_docs.exported_at');

        return $query;
    }
}
```

But when I get result for that scope all objects have id that is id from `to_requests` table.

For instance, if I try to get a row from `to_docs` table that has `id = 1` and this row has a foreign key `to_docs.request_id = 2` then the id for the model I get is also 2. However, when I remove a `join` section from scope method than everything works like a charm, `id` is 1

I probably could get rid of `join` but I need this condition to get rows which foreign record has `to_requests.deleted_at IS NULL`

Is there a way to fix this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve this issue. I knew that the problem was in join; however, I couldn't remove it because I need to refer field value in joined table. So I add `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::select` to fetch only fields from main table

```
public function scopeUnexported($query)
{
    $query
        ->select('to_docs.*')
        ->join('to_requests', function ($join) {
            $join->on('to_requests.id', '=', 'to_docs.request_id');
            $join->whereNull('to_requests.deleted_at');
        })
        ->where('to_docs.export_allowed', true)
        ->whereNotNull('to_docs.filename')
        ->whereNull('to_docs.exported_at');

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not strictly a Laravel question (or solution) as this is default behavior for mysql queries overwriting fields for empty joins. See also this answer [Join - fields in table 2 override those in table 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222111/join-fields-in-table-2-override-those-in-table-1) that provides a query-solution. A better, and more Laravelish way, would be to use eager loading (especially because you don't seem to use the joined data for sorting). See http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: It is true that I don't use data from to_requests table for sorting; however, I still need this join to limit select to get rows which related `to_requests.deteted_at IS NULL`.